# PHP incrementation of mixed content

Tags: php, increment

please, can you help me with a PHP function that increments mixed content (0-9, a-Z, _, -) like this?

```
private function increment_mix($id) {
    $chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_-"

    // I can not figure it out.
}

echo $this->increment_mix("5"); // 6
echo $this->increment_mix("Y"); // Z
echo $this->increment_mix("-"); // 00
echo $this->increment_mix("00"); // 01
echo $this->increment_mix("0z"); // 0A
echo $this->increment_mix("0-"); // 10
echo $this->increment_mix("mo"); // mp
echo $this->increment_mix("V--"); // W00
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].

Comment: Your expected outputs look kind of inconsistent.

Comment: First of all you should count string in increment_mix function ($id), srtlen($id).

If it's strlen($id) is one, then strpos of $id + 1..
This will get you trough the first part, try the second by yourself...

hint: breakpoints are on - charachter nex char is 0

Comment: The first part is simple, but the second not...

Comment: If there are two chars in string look for the value of second and if it's not -, increment its value (again use strpos), and watch out for case sensitive/insensitive functions in php, and if the second char is - increment the first and the second

Comment: @Don'tPanic there is consistency in expected outputs, take a closer look...

Comment: @Don'tPanic -> after 5 comes 6, after Y comes Z, after 00 comes 01, after 0z comes 0A (second position in $id string z->A).

Comment: @DenisSolakovic I understand it, but I'm not probably able to create expected cycle that I need in it. I must use for cycle in a while cycle and from the "for" cycle end the while...?

Comment: I see one case where one character becomes two characters (`"-": "00"`). In some cases with multiple characters, the first character is incremented (`"0-": "10"`, `"V--": "W00"`), and in others it isn't (`"00": "01"`, etc).

Comment: @Don'tPanic "V--" -> "W00", "ab--" -> ac00

Comment: if the last positioned char is -, than the next cycle increments the char positioned before ex.(0-)  - becomes 0, but beacose of new cycle the char before also increments so it'll give you 10

Comment: Shouldn't "00" become "11", "0z" become "1A", and "mo" become "np"?

Comment: And why does "-" become "00" instead of just "0"?

Comment: @Don'tPanic It increments only the LAST char, excluding the situation, when the last char is "-". In that case it increments char before the last char too (if it's not "-" again), etc...

Comment: 00 becomes 01, there's no looping trough the string because 0 is not the last char in the $chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_-", english is not my native, there is a saying in math something like, 12 +19 = (9+2 remember 1), and that remember 1 sets that zero from - to 00

Comment: Not binary, decimal or hexadecimal system, but something like "Sixty Quad System"

Comment: Ahhhhhhh ok. I see now. It didn't make sense to me as just string transformation. I didn't realize it was mathematical.

Comment: I tried this

`function next_id($id) {
  $chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_-";
  
  $lid = substr($id, -1);
  $pos = strpos($chars, $lid)+1;
  
  if($chars[$pos] == "") {
   
  }
  else {
   $str = substr($id, 0, -1).$chars[$pos];
  }

  return $str;
 }`

but instead of "if" I need cycle that controls the string from its end until the char isn't "-" and than increments all the "-"s... I don't know how to explain it better and my logical thinking probably isn't on required level :/

Comment: The condition is absolutely bad idea, I know, therefore I need to replace it directly by the cycle... Cycle that I'm not be able to create.

Comment: @RyanVincent Partly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that will do the job:

```
<?php
function increment_mix($id) {
    $chars = str_split("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_-");
    $parts = str_split(strrev($id));

    $firstChar = "first";

    if(isset($parts[0])){
        $firstChar = $parts[0];
    }

    $parts[0] = "increace|".$firstChar;

    for($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i++){
        if(strpos($parts[$i], "increace|") !== false){
            $charPart = str_replace("increace|", "", $parts[$i]);

            if($charPart == end($chars)){
                $parts[$i] = $chars[0];

                $nextChar = "first";

                if(isset($parts[$i+1])){
                    $nextChar = $parts[$i+1];
                }

                $parts[$i+1] = "increace|".$nextChar;
            }else{
                if($charPart == "first"){
                    $parts[$i] = $chars[0];
                }else{
                    $parts[$i] = $chars[array_search($charPart, $chars) + 1];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return strrev(implode("", $parts));
}
?>
```

EDIT: If you want to use other characters in an other order you just need to edit the string in `str_split()` on line 3

Comment: Thank you so much, I have to admit that it's really too much of logic for me.

Answer (score 1):

Marnix's answer isn't incorrect, but I think the logic here is easier to follow.

```
<?php

function increment_mix($id)
{
    // Set the initial position to the rightmost character
    $position = strlen($id) - 1;

    // While we haven't finished incrementing
    while (true) {
        // If we are trying to increment the position left of the first
        // character, then we should just append a 0 to the front and return
        if ($position < 0) {
            $id = '0' . $id;
            break;
        }

        // Try incrementing the single character at the current position
        $result = increment_single($id[$position]);

        if ($result === false) {
            // The current position resulted in a carry. Set the current
            // position to 0 and move our position left one character
            $id[$position] = 0;
            $position--;
        } else {
            // The current position did not result in a carry. Replace the
            // current position with the result from the single increment
            // and return.
            $id[$position] = $result;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $id;
}

/**
 * Increments a single character. Returns false if the operation resulted in
 * a carry.
 */
function increment_single($character)
{
    $chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_-";

    // Find the position of the character
    $position = strpos($chars, $character);
    // Increment it by 1
    $position++;

    if ($position >= strlen($chars)) {
        // The new position is past the end of the $chars string; carry
        return false;
    } else {
        // Return the char at the new position
        return $chars[$position];
    }
}

echo increment_mix("5"); // 6
echo "\n";
echo increment_mix("Y"); // Z
echo "\n";
echo increment_mix("-"); // 00
echo "\n";
echo increment_mix("00"); // 01
echo "\n";
echo increment_mix("0z"); // 0A
echo "\n";
echo increment_mix("0-"); // 10
echo "\n";
echo increment_mix("mo"); // mp
echo "\n";
echo increment_mix("V--"); // W00
echo "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks you, too :)